# Как изменить properties в jar?

Tags: java, потоки-данных, properties

Есть класс, который является оберткой для класса `Properties` который задумывался для получения доступа к значениям `config.properties` который находится внутри jar самого проекта:

```
public class Prop {

    public static final String EMAIL = "mail";
    public static final String PASS = "password";
    public static final String RECIPENTS = "recipents";
    public static final String FIO = "fio";
    public static final String USER = "user";
    public static final String EMAIL_JIRA = "mailJira";
    public static final String PASS_JIRA = "passwordJira";

    private Properties properties;

    private Reader reader;

    public Prop() {

        properties = new Properties();

        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("config.properties"), "utf-8"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            properties.load(reader);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public String get(String key) {
        return properties.getProperty(key);
    }

    public void set(String key, String value) {
        properties.setProperty(key, value);
    }
}
```

Каким образом можно изменить данные внутри файла `config.properties` с помощью метода `setProperty()`? На сколько я понял нужно работать с объектом класса `Properties`который перед редактированием мы `store()` (загрузим). Но как тогда получить или создать `OutputStreamWriter` по аналогии с `InputStreamReader`, и методом `getResourcesAsStream()`

Comment: Внутри jar - никак (если вы не хотите заморачиваться с перепаковкой jar и решать возможные проблемы блокировки этого jar на запись).

Comment: @Roman вы предлагаете использовать (например) ZipFileReader для чтения/записи из архива (jar ведь архив?). Просто суть задачи состоит в том что бы можно было бы параметризировать значения с которыми работает программа, но выносить файл вне jar и позволять пользователю случайно сломать ключи или вообще удалить файл config.properties тоже не хочется

Comment: Я предлагаю хранить файл снаружи jar. Многие программы хранят конфигурацию в отдельных файлах и не боятся, если пользователь их удалит (сам виноват).

Comment: @abbath0767 тогда создавайте jpa и пишите\читайте туда.  и пользователь не сможет ничего сломать

Comment: @Roman в ваших словах есть правда) наверное так и сделаем

Comment: при старте приложения вычитываете кастомный конфиг ${user.home.directory}/myapp-userconfig.properties если его нету - создаете его на основе файла которые у вас в джарнике. Кроме того вместо строковых констант лучше использовать enum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предложить такой вариант *(для linux, под windows адаптируйте по аналогии)*:

```
List<String> lines = Arrays.asList("hello", "world");
Files.write(Paths.get("file.txt"), lines, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
Process process = new ProcessBuilder().command("/bin/bash", "-c", "jar uf solution.jar file.txt").start();

System.out.println(process.waitFor());
```

Распишу поподробнее, что здесь происходит. Мы создаем файл `file.txt`, затем вызываем в консоли команду `jar uf <название jar архива>.jar <название файлов которые хотим добавить>`. Запускаем процесс, ждем его завершения и выводим код возврата. Если он !=0, то случилась беда и где то произошла ошибка.

Comment: `int exitCode = process.waitFor();` лучше, чем пустой цикл.

Comment: интересное решение. Файл txt можно без проблем заменить на properties и обойтись без списка строк. Возможно. Но вот меня пугает перспектива потока выполняемой программы jar файла пытаться изменить самого себя - это не может привести к каким нибудь проблемам? Тем не менее я попробую такое решение

Comment: @Roman спасибо, хорошее замечание

Comment: @abbath0767 вообще хранение изменяемых файлов  в jar архиве это не очень хорошая практика. они должны быть read-only.

Comment: А как бы вы посоветовали бы реализовать следующую проблему: есть проект который отвечает за сбор данных и отправку некоего отчета, но проект должен поддерживать возможность изменять параметры с которыми он работает, например получив jar один пользователь использует свою связку ключей-паролей, другой соответственно другую. Единственный вариант на мой взгляд это использование файла properties вне проекта, но тогда пользователь получает доступ к файлу и его данным (в т.ч. ключам) которые желательно не трогать.

Comment: @abbath0767 вас смущает именно наличие файлов рядом с jar или то что их может прочесть конечный пользователь?

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov скорее само наличие рядом с jar. Данные которые являются в properties значением можно попробовать зашифровать (как и внутри jar на данный момент). Но в теории это не настолько критично, насколько плохая практика хранения изменяемых файлов внутри исполняемого jar, так как проект все таки больше для себя)

Comment: Я бы порекомендовал все же положить рядом с jar